# For two differentiable functions $f,g$ show that $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have two differentiable functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f'=g$, $g'=-f$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$. I need to show that $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x.$

I defined $h(x)= f(x)^2 + g(x)^2$. I can take $$h' = (f^2+g^2)' = (ff)' + (gg)' = 2f'f + 2g'g = 2gf - 2gf = 0$$ So $h(x)=f(x)^2+g(x)^2=0$ for all $x$ since $h(0)=0^2+0^2=0$ and $h$ is constant. How can I proceed?

Comment: $h(x)$ is the squared norm of the vector $(f(x), g(x))$. The norm is zero iff the vector is...

Comment: Well, you’re basically done! Look at $h$ more closely. Were either $f$ or $g$ nonzero for some $c$, what would that mean for $h$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$f^2(x) \leq f^2(x)+g^2(x)=0$$ for all $x.$ Thus, $f^2(x)=0$ for all $x.$ Hence, $f(x)=0$ for all $x.$

Similarly, $g(x)=0$ for all $x.$

Answer (score 2):

If the OP is familiar with ODE we may show this alternatively like this: $f'=g\Longrightarrow f''=g'$ and since $g'=-f$ we have a homogoneous ODE of second order equation with constant coefficients $f''+f=0$ with homogeneous intial conditions  $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. This implies that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ by the uniqueness. Since $f=0$ and $g'=-f$, $g'=0$ and hence $g(x)$=constant. Since $g(0)=0$, constant $=0$, so $g(x)=0$.

Comment: nice way to do it, just note that the last part can be done easier, $f$ is a constant hence $f'=0$ and $f'=g$ hence $g=0$

Comment: I think OP's approach in question is far simpler than using theory of ODE.

Comment: respect your thought

Answer (score 1):

$$h(x)=\|(f(x),g(x))\|_2^2=0\implies \|(f(x),g(x))\|_2=0$$ now using triangle inequality we have$$0\ge\|(f(x),g(x))\|_1\ge\|(f(x),g(x))\|_2$$using the squeeze theorem we get $$f(x)+g(x)=0\implies f(x)=-g(x)\implies f^2(x)=g^2(x)\implies 2g^2(x)=f^2(x)+g^2(x)=h(x)=0\implies 2g^2(x)=0\implies g(x)=0\implies f(x)=-0=0$$